# Python while loop with user input

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input

I have this simple little program which doesn't work. I want the program to keep asking the user for my name till they guess it.

The program throws an error message after the first attempt. I can't work it out where the problem is.

```
name = "not_aneta"

while name != "aneta":
    name = input("What is my name? ")

if name == "aneta":
    print "You guessed my name!"
```

When I run it I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aneta\Desktop\guess_my_name.py", line 4, in <module>
    name = input("What is my name? ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'aneta' is not defined
```

Comment: You are using python 2.X and need to use `raw_input`.The `input` function in python 2.X will evaluated the input, so it have raised `NameError`  when you wanted to use it in `name == "aneta"`

Comment: Use `raw_input` in place of `input` if you are using python2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use `raw_input` (`input` tries to run the input as a python expression and this is not what you want) and fix the indentation problem.

```
name = "not_aneta"

while name!= "aneta":
    name = raw_input("What is my name? ")

    if name == "aneta":
        print "You guessed my name!"
```

Comment: Actually we don't need `if` here. You can put  `print "You guessed my name!"` outside the `while` loop. Or for more clear, you can use `else` like `else: print "You guessed my name!"`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your are using 2.x so you need `raw_input` for strings.

```
name = "not_aneta"

while name!= "aneta":
    name = raw_input("What is my name? ")
```

also, the `if` statements is pretty pointless because the program won't continue until the user guesses the correct name. So you could just do:

```
name = "not_aneta"

while name!= "aneta":
    name = raw_input("What is my name? ")

print "You guessed my name!"
```